# How does WebStorm syntax inspection can recognize ES6 syntax "..."?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I used ES6 syntax `...` in my code for unpack an array, example:

```
var fn = function(arg0, arg1, arg2) {
    // use arguments here.
};
fn(...[1, 2, 3]);
```

but my WebStorm can't distinguish this syntax. How to set up WebStorm to fix this problem?

WebStorm version: 11.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Javascript
>   language version -> choose [ECMAScript 6]

[Official docs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/)